# Is there a way to collect information about whether the user installed a MSI using SCCM? (Either during installtion itself or after installtion)

Tags: windows-installer

I want to add installer analytics to one of my MSI installer and I would like to know if that MSI is installed through SCCM Client after an Admin pushes it? Is there a way to get that info during installation itself? Or after user installed it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unless SCCM puts some indications somewhere (such as by passing a property on the command line - check a verbose log), the only idea I have is to create a heuristic based on the original location of the source package, perhaps checking it for per-user or per-machine locations.

If you want to check this during the original install, you could check the property [SourceDir](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371857.aspx). (If this property is not set, that indicates you are running some form of maintenance that hasn't executed a ResolveSource action.)

If you want to check after the fact from outside the install, you can use the C++ API [MsiGetProductInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370130.aspx)(szProductCode, INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLSOURCE, ...) or the COM-based API [Product.InstallProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370865.aspx)(INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLSOURCE) to retrieve the same information.